# CSS bar with controls to the right

Tags: css, user-interface

[Here's a nice jsFiddle illustrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/66dgy0Lm/1/)

I'm trying to create a titlebar element which...

- is only ever 1 line tall
- has controls in the top right which are always present
- has a title in the top left, which gets truncated with "..." if it's too long

Does anyone know how I'd go about fixing this? I'm a bit stumped.

```css
.item {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 25%;
}

.titlebar {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.title {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

i {
    font-style: normal;
    float: right;
}

.content {
    min-height: 15em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <span class="title">My title</span>
        <span class="controls">
            <i>-</i><i>+</i><i>X</i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is the most simple use-case - a nice short title, everything works tickety-boo.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <span class="title">My title which is just right...</span>
        <span class="controls">
            <i>-</i><i>+</i><i>X</i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is how it should look if the title is too long (obviously this title is just the right length, but pretend there are other words after it).
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <span class="title">My title which is really far too long for a sensible title to be</span>
        <span class="controls">
            <i>-</i><i>+</i><i>X</i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is the problem: the title is way longer than can fit, and it pushes the buttons down on to a second line.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution without fixed sizes change the order of the `.title` and `.controls` in the html. This makes sure that when you set `float: right` on the `.controls` that the controls are rendered first and will occur on the first line. After this you need to have `overflow: hidden`, `text-overflow: ellipsis`, `white-space: nowrap` and `display: block` on the `.title`

I've updated your example to reflect this.

```css
.item {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 25%;
}

.titlebar {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.title {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
    display: block;
}

i {
    font-style: normal;
    float: right;
}

.content {
    min-height: 15em;
}

.controls {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <span class="controls">
            <i>-</i><i>+</i><i>X</i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">My title</span>      
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is the most simple use-case - a nice short title, everything works tickety-boo.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <span class="controls">
            <i>-</i><i>+</i><i>X</i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">My title which is just right...</span>      
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is how it should look if the title is too long (obviously this title is just the right length, but pretend there are other words after it).
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="titlebar">
        <span class="controls">
            <i>-</i><i>+</i><i>X</i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">My title which is really far too long for a sensible title to be</span>      
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is the problem: the title is way longer than can fit, and it pushes the buttons down on to a second line.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice - no fixed widths is perfect :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer.

I floated the objects and gave them a width of `70%` and `30%`.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/66dgy0Lm/2/)

Hope this helps you, and is what you're looking for. if not, add a comment and i'll try to help you.